# More efficient method for this calculation?

Tags: python, iteration, long-integer, largenumber

```
a = 218500000000

s = 6
f = 2
k = 49
d = k + f + s

r = a
i = 0

while (r >= d):
  r = r - d
  #print ('r = ',r)
  i = i+1
  #print ('i = ',i)

print (i)
```

I think it does what I expect it to, but its way too slow to calculate such a large number, I waited 5 mins for i to print (while python used 100% cpu to calculate..), but it didn't. Is there a more efficient way of rewriting this piece of code so I can see how many iterations (i) it takes to complete?

Many thanks

Comment: What do you actually want it to do? What are you calculating?

Comment: @S.Lott: I wish SO existed while I was in school or even college. :)

Comment: @nimbuz: If it's not homework, please provide some context for why you're doing something so grotesquely inefficient.  Where did you get this algorithm?  Why are you using it?  Only homework can justify such a terrible way to do a simple thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
r = (a % d)
i = (a / d)
```

Use the [modulo and division operators](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations).

There is also a divmod function to calculate both together:

```
i, r = divmod(a,d)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `i = a/d`. :D

Comment: Oh, is division faster than addition/subtraction? I'd love to know why! :)

Comment: Got the answer btw, 3833333333.33. Still, would like to know why division is faster?

Comment: @:Nimbuz, That depends, division of power-two number like 2, 4, 8, ... is as fast as addition and subtraction. Even when the number is not power-two number, doing so division is still faster than so many addition/subtraction. Also with modern hardware, the division is performed with a the same clock cycle as addition/subtraction.

Comment: @Nimbuz, if you had to multiply `1000*234` would you sum `234` a thousand times or would you apply the multiplication algorithm?

Comment: @:Numbuz, In your case, you are doing more that just a few addition/subtraction. In each loop, you do one add for `i`, one subtract for `r` and a condition of `r` and `d`. AND you are doing that million of times :p.

Comment: @Nimbuz, About the decimal `.33`. You can cast it back to in using `(int)a/d`. :-D Cheer!

Answer (score 2):

Isn't a division what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

try `3833333333.3333333333333333333333`. AKA `r / d`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing truncating division to me.  That is, you want to find out how many times d goes into a without knowing the remainder.

```
a = 218500000000
s = 6
f = 2
k = 49
d = k + f + s

i = a // d

print (i)
```